# C++ Passing class by value

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

When i run the following program in XCode Version 5.1.1,

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass Cons " << this << std::endl;}
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass Dest " << this << std::endl;}

};
void Func(MyClass myClass)
{

}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass myClass1;
    Func(myClass1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output i get is

```
MyClass Cons 0x7fff5fbff918
MyClass Dest 0x7fff5fbff910
MyClass Dest 0x7fff5fbff918
```

Why is the destructor triggering twice and constructor only once?

Comment: You are making a copy. You need to provide a verbose copy constructor too.

Answer (score 5):

The object is destroyed once, as you can see from the pointer values. You also see the destruction of another object. This object is a copy of the original.

By passing the object by value, the `copy-constructor` is invoked. Since this constructor does not print something, you do not see it in your output.

Add it to the class definition:

```
MyClass(const MyClass & other) { std::cout << "MyClass Copy-Cons " << this << " from " << &other << std::endl;}
```

And it should appear:

```
MyClass Cons 0x7fff1beee7ee
MyClass Copy-Cons 0x7fff1beee7ef from 0x7fff1beee7ee
MyClass Dest 0x7fff1beee7ef
MyClass Dest 0x7fff1beee7ee
```

The copy is created when you enter `Func()`. The copy is destroyed when it goes out of scope. This happens when you exit `Func()`. Finally, the original is destroyed when you exit the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are seeing two destructor is because you are pass the arguments by value. Passing by value calls the copy constructor..

First Destructor:

`At the end of the func function, the object goes out of scope, hence, it is destructed`.

Second Destructor:

```
When the program end, the object is destructed.
```

My suggestion to remove the first destructor is to pass the object by reference rather than by value.

For example,

```
void Func(MyClass &myClass)
{

}
```

So now the output will have only:

```
MyClass Cons 0x7fff5fbff918
MyClass Dest 0x7fff5fbff918
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the object is constructed twice(as everyone mentioned above). Hence 2 constructor + 2 destructor are called. The reason you are seeing 1 constructor is because you have NOT defined the Copy Constructor. CC is called when a copy is made for the pass-by-value operation.

add the copy constructor and then you can see both the constructor called.

Add Copy constructor - MyClass(const MyClass& obj) { std::cout << "MyClass Copy Cons " << this << std::endl;}